# how to pass in slug url in django template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i want to pass in a slug in my django template so i can be able to add a post as favourite but i do not know the right way to pass in the slug this is what i have done `href="{% url 'elements:favourite' elements_slug.slug %}`

```
<a href="{% url 'elements:favourite' elements_slug.slug %}" class="btn">Favourite</a>
```

views.py

```
def favourite(request, elements_slug):
    user = request.user
    elements = Elements.objects.get(slug=elements_slug)
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

    if profile.favourite.filter(slug=elements_slug).exists():
        profile.favourite.remove(elements)
    else:
        profile.favourite.add(elements)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('elements:vector-details', args=[elements_slug]))
```

**UPDATED WITH ERROR**
error

```
Reverse for 'favourite' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['elements/(?P<elements_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/favourite$']
```

Comment: what error are you facing?

Comment: Possibly duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53067186/how-to-use-slugs-in-django-url

Comment: @rahul.m i update the question with the error

Comment: @rahul.m thank it answered my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it

```
<a href="{% url 'favourite' slug=instance.slug %}">Favourite</a>
```